# Wrong baked normals projections

Tags: normals, texture-baking, texture-painting, normal-map

I was modelling a Sniper Rifle,my HighPoly model has about 3M tris ,so i find kinda slow to work with this highpoly mesh. I Used the SAME models to work with in low poly,but used a low subdivision surface number in it, got 300k tris.I Used the "AutoSmooth" option.

I tried bake in a bunch of softwares, but the one i've got the best results was Substance Painter 2, it fixed a lot of projections with the "Match by mesh name" function.

My Workflow was simplified by:

1. Model HighPoly
2. Duplicate all objects and reduce de Subdivision surface to 1
3. Join All LowPoly objects(with all modifiers applied), and the same to highPoly;
4. UV Unrwap(I Used Smart UV,without "Stretch to bounds" and then, "Average Islands")
5. Separate all objects ,rename them with "_low" sufix and then
   group them in a low poly group(The single UV Map was preserved, i wanted this);
6. Rename all HighPoly with "_high" sufix and group them in a high
   poly group;
7. Export All low poly in a single .fbx file;
8. Export All High poly in a single .fbx file;
9. Bake normals.

But i've got some projections errors. One of them i couldn't fix by myself and here's a picture that shows the problem.

[image]
I was trying to find out where's is the problem,but i don't know once i'm kinda new to modelling world.

In some tests i was able to render it in Marmoset Toolbag,but once i zoom in those baked normals start to popout and look terrible.

Can you guys help me please?Thank you in advance